# Oracle Missing Defines Issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

The sample below illustrated the problem that I am having.  Basically if you execute the DDL below then execute the Proc MissingDefinesTest with 1 and 2 as an input everything is OK.  However when I execute the same proc with 1 and 1 as an input I get the MissingDefines error message which I believe is due to the empty result set coming back from the second cursor.  Does any one know why or know how to fix this.  I went through the lengths of defining types, etc... but ended up with the same issue.

```
create table TableA
(
  aid int
);
/
create table TableB
(
  bid int
);
/
insert into tablea(aid) select 1 from dual;
insert into tableb(bid) select 2 from dual;
/
create or replace PROCEDURE MissingDefinesTest
(
a_id int,
b_id int,
ACUR          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
BCUR          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)  
is 
begin

OPEN ACUR FOR select * from TableA where aid = a_id;
OPEN BCUR FOR select * from TableB where bid = b_id;
end;
/
```

Comment: How are you calling the procedure and supplying the out parameters? Are you seeing this in a particular client, or version? I used to get an annoying 'missing defines' message in SQL Developer, but I'm not seeing it with this code, in 4.1.3, 4.1.5 or 4.2.0 - and i'm not sure that's what you're talking about anyway.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors for your test case in SQL*Plus 11.2.0.2 or PL/SQL Developer 11.0.2 on Oracle 12.1.0.2.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out.  This is interesting information.  I am using RapidSQL.  I just checked against some C# code and it works fine.  Looks like my problem is RapidSQL  FYI I am running Version 2016.5 Build 14530, 64Bit. Arghhhhhhh!

Comment: It seems the RapidSQL installation on my machine is causing the issue.  I have checked with other DEV boxes and there is no problem.  I have tried uninstall/reinstall with no luck.  Arghhh.  Toad, SqlDev, etc.. all seem to work fine. Very frustrating...In any case this issue is resolved, less anyone wants to say they had the same problem with RapidSQL and fixed it somehow.